# smart gwt developer console

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Hello all
I am using smart gwt 2.3 pro version with Mozilla on windows xp system.
I made Test Application on it & it is running successfully.
Now I want to use developer console for this application.
I gwt.xml coding is like below.

```
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.tools.SmartGwtTools"/>
```

Now After compiling and running it I am writing 
javascript:isc.showConsole()
to my browser.
But is it doing nothing.
I am not getting what to do else for developer console.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Easiest way is to put a bookmark in your FireFox toolbar and so all you have to do is click on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to double check, did you put the javascript:isc.showConsole() in the address bar of the window where your GWT app was running?

You need to replace the URL of your app with javascript:isc.showConsole() and hit enter.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're running it from GWT code, I would suggest you to use the wrapper

```
SC.showConsole();
```

If all the inherits are in place, that should work